# u_int32_t vs bpf_u_int32

Tags: c++, c, int

I've been busy doing some network programming over the past couple of days and I cant seem to figure out a difference between the data types u_int32_t abd bpf_u_int32.

u_int32_t means 32 unsigned bits. Doesnt bpf_u_int32 mean the same? 
Because some functions read the IP address in one form or the other.
Some functions in the pcap library like pcap_lookupnet require the net address to be of the form bpf_u_int32.

I am curious to know the difference

Comment: Neither of these types are in standard C nor standard C++. You have to look up their documentation to find out.

Comment: u_int32_t means 32 bits, taken as a single quantity and treated as unsigned.  You can't have 32 individual bits each being signed or unsigned; that makes no sense.  But you probably knew that & fudged your question's wording.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmers add layers of indirection for a living. They're almost certainly the same type, you can check that in C++ with `#include <typeinfo>` followed by `typeid(u_int32_t) == typeid(bpf_u_int32)`.

On some implementations there's at least the possibility that one is `unsigned int` and the other is `unsigned long`.

What's happened is that two different people have independently chosen a name for a 32 bit unsigned type (or maybe the same person for two slightly different purposes). One of them has used a "bpf" prefix, which in this context stands for Berkeley Packet Filter since that's relevant to packet capture. The other one hasn't. One has used the `_t` suffix that indicates a type name, the other hasn't. Aside from that, they picked similar names.

C99 and C++11 both introduce a standard name for a 32 bit unsigned type: `uint32_t`. That won't stop people creating their own aliases for it, though.

Comment: wouldn't std::is_same be more appropriate?

Comment: @MFH: if you like. It has the advantage of being a compile-time test and the disadvantage of not being in C++03. If I'm writing a five-line program to test something like this, I really don't care when the test is performed. I do care if someone who asks a question on SO and doesn't know the difference between C++03 and C++11 can't make my answer work ;-)

Comment: I think that this kind of test belongs directly into the program (as definitions may change) and preferably are tested at compile time and prevent compilation if the assumption that they are equal fails. BTW: is_same is not included in C++03 but is valid C++03 (4 lines of code max)

Comment: @MFH: I don't really understand your point. I'm not talking about incorporating the test into the questioner's program, I'm talking about satisfying the questioner's curiosity. I don't think the questioner has given any indication of wanting to write code that should fail to compile in the case where they're different types, or that otherwise makes an assumption that they are the same type.

Comment: On various systems, bpf_u_int32 is typedef'ed from uint_t, u_int, u_int32, u_int_32, or conceivably "unsigned long", whatever results in a 32-bit unsigned integer on a given system.  See http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/trackident?im=10;i=bpf_u_int32 for various implementations' header files defining it.  Defining it in one place makes it possible to use the remainder of the code on multiple systems without customizing the bulk of the code to each system.

Comment: @SteveJessop: If he is in fact going to rely on that assumption in his code than such a check BELONGS into the code! Breaking such a central assumption should always lead to abortion of compilation!

Comment: @MFH: if. It would be better to not write code that makes such an assumption. Since the two are both integer types, and certainly convert to one another without loss of information, there's not much need to write code that relies on them being the same type. A template function with a `static` local variable could do it, for example, but I'm pretty sure that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

Both types are most likely typedefs to a 32-bit unsigned type. As such, they can be considered equivalent and there is no useful difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

Check type always from bpf.h file you are really using. This is a bpf.h:

**#ifdef MSDOS /* must be 32-bit */**

typedef long          bpf_int32;

typedef unsigned long bpf_u_int32;

**#else**

typedef int bpf_int32;

typedef u_int bpf_u_int32;

**#endif**